# Determine whether $*$ is associative, where $*$ is defined on $\Bbb Z^+$ by $a*b=2^{ab}$.

Tags: group-theory

I am doing this group theory question:

[image]

I have already proven that * is commutative, however, I'm I bit confused about proving for associativity.

I used three variables a, b and c and said: RTF whether a*(b*c) = (a*b)*c

For the right hand side of the equation I got: 2^(2^(bc) a)

For the left hand side of the equation I got: 2^(2^(ab) c)

I know these two appear to be different, but my question is, is there away to simplify what is there, because I'm unsure if they are actually the same or not.

Comment: Try some small $a,b,c$, say $b=c=1$. You can decide about $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, $(a*b)*c = 2^{(a*b)c} = 2^{2^{ab}c}$ vs. $a*(b*c) = 2^{a(b*c)} = 2^{a2^{bc}}$.  For these two to be equal, then we would need:

$$
c2^{ab} = a2^{bc}
$$

These are clearly not equal for all $a$, $b$, $c$.  Simply choose $a$ and $c$ to be relatively prime and then there is no way for these to be equal (in fact, I suspect the only way for these to be equal is for $a = c$).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find a counterexample to these.  Just take the numbers $2,3,5$.  We have that

\begin{eqnarray*}
(2*3)*5 & = & (2^6)*5 \;\; =\;\; 2^{64\times 5} \;\; =\;\; 2^{320} \\
2*(3*5) & =  & 2*(2^{15}) \;\; =\;\; 2^{2 \times 32,768} \;\; =\;\; 2^{65,536}
\end{eqnarray*}

which are quite different from one another.